# Whats The Difference Between These Cmdlets?

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell 3 if you are searching for a command you could use both, both Get-Help Get-* and Get-Command Get-* work?

So whats the major difference ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both commands share a lot of information in common but the main difference is that `Get-Help` outputs MAML objects (which are "text based", error prone and even can be out dated) while `Get-Command` gets you real objects (metadata), that you can further investigate.

For most help parts, `Get-Help` is displaying pre-made help, contained in XML files.
For other parts, `Get-Help` "is using" `Get-Command` to generate the information, like the SYNTAX section.

`Get-Command` also gets you information that Get-Help doesn't, like the module of the command, , it's DLL path (in case of a compiled cmdlet), parameter sets, and so on.

One is not a replacement for the other, you use both under different circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

The way I think of it is - `Get-Command` returns the *technical* information about commands (DLL, implementing type, function body for functions, etc), `Get-Help` returns the *user-friendly* information about commands (detailed syntax, examples, explanation of parameters, etc).

And `Get-Command` returns a normal object, which behaves perfectly normally and predictably, whereas `Get-Help` returns a weird formatted help object which is really only intended for viewing in the console, not for processing in code.